# Interval comparison doesn't bomb in JS

Tags: javascript, boolean, intervals

Why doesn't interval comparison bomb in JavaScript?

```
if(-1 < x < 1) {
  console.log('x: ', x)
}
```

Why are we allowed to do this without getting errors?

Also it seems that:

- `-1 < x < 1` is true for `x<=-1`
- `1 < x < 1` is true for `x<=1`
- `-1 < x < -1` is always false
- `-2 < x < 2` is always true

In the last 2 cases it seems it is just comparing the 2 ends of the expressions. How are those expressions evalued?

Comment: They are evaluated as `(-1 < x) < 1`, which is equivalent to `(-1 < x) != true` or `!(-1 < x)`

Comment: What you really need is `-1 < x && x < 1`

Comment: @HerrSerker I know how to do proper comparisons, I was just asking how JS evaluated what in other languages is called interval comparisons.

Comment: I knew this. But it would be interesting to other people who want to know, how it's done right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because JavaScript allows implicit type coercion, in this case from boolean to number. The `-1 < x` results in a boolean, which is then implicitly coerced to a number (true = 1, false = 0) for the `(result) < 1` part. So:

- When `-1 < x` is false, the second part is `0 < 1` which is true.
- When `-1 < x` is true, the second part is `1 < 1` which is false.

This is covered in the [abstract relational comparison](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-abstract-relational-comparison) algorithm in the spec, and the various operations it links to.

> ```
> -1 < x < -1 is always false
> -2 < x < 2 is always true
> ```
>
> In the last 2 cases it seems it is just comparing the 2 ends of the expressions. How are those expressions evalued?

Using `x = -1` and `x = 1`:

- If `x = -1`, then `-1 < x` is false, so the rest is `0 < -1`, which is false.
- If `x = 1`, then `-1 < 1` is true, so the rest is `1 < -1` which is false.
- If `x = -1`, then `-2 < -1` is true, so the rest is `1 < -2`, which is false.
- If `x = 1`, then `-2 < 1` is true, so the rest is `1 < -2` which is false.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this happens because javascript implicitly considers `true` to have the value `1` and `false` to have the value `0`.

When you do `-1 < x < 1`, what you're actually doing is `(-1 < x) < 1`, or `true < 1` if `x = 0` which is `false`.

However, if `x=-2`, `(-1 < x < -1)` will return `true` as `false < 1` is `true`. Hope this helps.

You can read more about this here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators

Answer (score -1):

The reason is that JS interprets your expression.

```
if((-1 < x) < 1) {
  console.log('x: ', x)
}
```

Trying using braces...