# Trouble with increments on variable values

Tags: javascript, variables

I'm having real trouble with increments on variable values, the code executes fine but the "q1tries" variable only increments from 0 to 1 and then stops, I'm looking to increment to 3 and then alert the answer.

I'm very new to javascript and any suggestions would be much appreciated.

```
function quiz(){
    q1();
    q2();
}

const q1 = function(){    
    var q1answer ="24000"
    var q1tries = 0;

q1prompt = prompt("What is 23745 to the nearest thousand?");
if (q1prompt == q1answer){
    alert("Well done! " + person + ", you're score is " + ++score)
    alert("You have taken " + ++q1tries + " tries.");
}

else {
    alert("Sorry " + person + " that's the wrong answer, you're score is " + score)
    alert("You have taken " + ++q1tries + " tries.");
}

while (q1tries >1 <3){
    q1();
}

while (q1tries == 3) {
    alert(q1answer);
}
```

}

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript (like most programming languages) doesn't support `q1tries > 1 < 3` comparisons. Instead, you use the `&&` (AND) operator and repeat the variable name:

```
while (q1tries > 1 && q1tries < 3)
```

The reason you don't get an error (*un*like most programming languages) is explained in [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53320337/157247) (briefly: because `q1tries > 1` results in a boolean, and JavaScript allows implicit coercion of booleans to numbers, so the result is coerced to number and used in the `(result) < 3` part).

Comment: Thank you so much for your swift reply!

I'll add in the &&, repeat the variable name and see if that does it!